# Reflections for ReGIS graphics screen scraping in C# .NET API

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a windows forms application that can scrub screen information from a Reflections window. The problem is that it's an older version of reflections from back when WRQ still owned the app. Since Attachmate have taken it over, I can't find any documentation on the .net API related to this older version.

What I have so far is this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openApp();
}
private void openApp()
{
    // Create a new instance of Reflection.
    Reflection4.Session reflection = new Reflection4.Session();
    reflection.Visible = true;
}
```

So this is fine for opening a new Reflections window, but I want it to run the screen scrape on a window that is already open.

Comment: Please tell us what "Reflections" and "ReGIS" is in the context of your question. We don't know who WRQ is either.

Comment: "Reflections for ReGIS graphics" is a windows terminal emulator. "WRQ" are the company that used to own the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a way to get the first active Reflection4.Session using [Marshal.GetActiveObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx). I found the progid for Reflection4 using the [ProgID Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911706.aspx) website on MSDN. With that I found that the following code works:

```
Reflection4.Session session = (Marshal.GetActiveObject("Reflection4.Session.8") as Reflection4.Session);
```